# How to share AngularFire setup between a project and an included custom library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7, angularfire

So far I've got an Angular 7 project, that has couple of modules in itself and also my custom library with outsourced common functionality and both the project and the library have to use AngularFire. The problem that I get when I try to do the next setup is that I get an error like this when I visit my website from browser.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
    at _createClass (core.js:21271)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:21235)
```

Here's the setup of the modules:

app.module.ts

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
    import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
    import { CoreModule, firebaseConfig } from "./core/core.module";
    import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";
    import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
    import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
    import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
    import { NgPipesModule } from "ngx-pipes";
    import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
    import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from "angular-highcharts";

    import { ScrollToModule } from "ng2-scroll-to-el";
    import { NgCircleProgressModule } from "ng-circle-progress";
    import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/auth";
    import { AngularFireStorageModule } from "@angular/fire/storage";
    import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

    export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
       return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
    }

    declare var require: any;

    @NgModule({
       declarations: [AppComponent],
       imports: [
           BrowserModule,
           AppRoutingModule,
           SharedModule,
           CoreModule,
           FormsModule,
           NgPipesModule,
           HttpClientModule,
           BrowserAnimationsModule,
           NgbModule,
           ChartModule,
           AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
           AngularFireAuthModule,
           AngularFireStorageModule,
           AngularFirestoreModule,
           TranslateModule.forRoot({
               loader: {
                   provide: TranslateLoader,
                   useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                   deps: [HttpClient]
               }
           }),
           NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({}),
           ScrollToModule.forRoot()
       ],
       providers: [
           {
               provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES,
               useFactory: () => [require("highcharts/highcharts-more.src")]
           } // add as factory to your providers
       ],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Core.module.ts:

```js
    import {
        Compiler,
        COMPILER_OPTIONS,
        CompilerFactory,
        NgModule
    } from "@angular/core";
    import { JitCompilerFactory } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
    import { registerLocaleData } from "@angular/common";
    import localeUk from "@angular/common/locales/uk";

    registerLocaleData(localeUk);
    import { HeaderComponent } from "./header/header.component";
    import { AppRoutingModule } from "../app-routing.module";
    import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";
    import { CoreRoutingModule } from "./core-routing.module";
    import { MainAreaComponent } from "./main-area/main-area.component";
    import { TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
    import { StrengthsService } from "./strengths.service";
    import { ScoreCardsService } from "./score-cards.service";
    import { GroupsService } from "./groups.service";
    import { StudentsService } from "./students.service";
    import { TutorsService } from "./tutors.service";
    import { SubjectsService } from "./subjects.service";
    import { ConditionsService } from "./conditions.service";
    import { ChartsDataService } from "./charts/charts-data.service";
    import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
    import { SettingsService } from "./settings.service";
    import { AuthService, TCoreModule } from "@eriendel/t-core";
    import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";

    export function createCompiler(fn: CompilerFactory): Compiler {
        return fn.createCompiler();
    }
    export const firebaseConfig = environment.firebaseConfig;

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [HeaderComponent, MainAreaComponent],
        imports: [
            SharedModule,
            AppRoutingModule,
            CoreRoutingModule,
            TranslateModule.forChild(),
            NgbModule,
            TCoreModule.forChild({
                autoAuthRoleCredentials: environment.autoAuthRoleCredentials
            })
        ],
        exports: [AppRoutingModule, HeaderComponent],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS,
                useValue: {},
                multi: true
            },
            {
                provide: CompilerFactory,
                useClass: JitCompilerFactory,
                deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS]
            },
            {
                provide: Compiler,
                useFactory: createCompiler,
                deps: [CompilerFactory]
            },
            ScoreCardsService,
            StrengthsService,
            GroupsService,
            StudentsService,
            TutorsService,
            SubjectsService,
            ConditionsService,
            ChartsDataService,
            SettingsService,
            AuthService
        ]
    })
    export class CoreModule {}
```

And the module of my library t-core.module.ts:

```js
    import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from "@angular/core";
    import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
    import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
    import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
    import { CommonModule, registerLocaleData } from "@angular/common";
    import localeUk from "@angular/common/locales/uk";
    registerLocaleData(localeUk);

    import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
    import { LoggingInterceptor } from "./logging.interceptor";
    import { NotFoundComponent } from "./not-found/not-found.component";
    import { SidebarComponent } from "./sidebar/sidebar.component";
    import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
    import { DatesService } from "./dates.service";
    import { LocalizationService } from "./localization.service";
    import { CalculationsService } from "./calculations/calculations.service";
    import { NavService } from "./nav.service";
    import { SigninComponent } from "./auth/signin/signin.component";
    import { ChangePassComponent } from "./auth/change-pass/change-pass.component";
    import { AntiAuthGuard } from "./auth/antiAuth.guard";
    import {
        AuthGuard,
        AutoAuthRoleCredential,
        AUTO_AUTH_ROLE_CREDENTIALS
    } from "./auth.guard";
    import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
    import { HttpLoaderFactory } from "./HttpLoaderFactory";
    import { UIModule } from "./ui/ui.module";
    import { AngularFireModule, FirebaseAppConfig } from "@angular/fire";
    import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
    import {
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFirestore
    } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
    import { AngularFireStorageModule } from "@angular/fire/storage";

    export interface TCoreModuleConfig {
        autoAuthRoleCredentials: AutoAuthRoleCredential[];
    }

    // @dynamic

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
            NotFoundComponent,
            SidebarComponent,
            SigninComponent,
            ChangePassComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            RouterModule,
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            UIModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                    deps: [HttpClient]
                }
            }),
            NgbModule
        ],
        exports: [
            SidebarComponent,
            NotFoundComponent,
            SigninComponent,
            ChangePassComponent
        ]
    })
    export class TCoreModule {
        static forRoot(config: TCoreModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
            return {
                ngModule: TCoreModule,
                providers: [
                    AuthService,
                    CalculationsService,
                    DatesService,
                    LocalizationService,
                    NavService,
                    AntiAuthGuard,
                    AuthGuard,
                    {
                        provide: AUTO_AUTH_ROLE_CREDENTIALS,
                        useValue: config.autoAuthRoleCredentials
                    },
                    {
                        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                        useClass: LoggingInterceptor,
                        multi: true
                    },
                    {
                        provide: LOCALE_ID,
                        deps: [LocalizationService],
                        useFactory: localizationService =>
                            localizationService.getLocale()
                    },
                    AngularFirestore,
                    AngularFireAuth
                ]
            };
        }

        static forChild(config: TCoreModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
            return this.forRoot(config);
        }
    }
```

So the problem here as I see is that I have no possibility to initialize AngularFireModule in my underying library module. For that I'd have to have the firebase config available in the import section of t-core` module and that could only be injected in the forRoot() method of the t-core module class, which is too late to do import AFAIK.

Is there any other way to make this work?

Comment: Hi did you try moving the Core module import in App module after the import of
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
AngularFireAuthModule,
AngularFireStorageModule
in imports

Comment: As you are using AngularFirestore service in t-core module before initialization of AngularFireModule

Comment: @Eriendel did you make it work? I'm with the same problem

Comment: @elranu no, man, I gave up on that idea.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting this to work as well. I found a surprising solution. [Here's a minimal replication of that solution.](https://github.com/trevorhreed/angular-fire-in-angular-library)

In short, I don't initialize or even include Angular Fire in the library module directly. I initialize and include it only in the application module. It seems the library module can automatically take advantage of Angular Fire once everything gets imported into and compiled with the Application module.

Here's a view of the relevant code:

### Library Module

**shared.module.ts**

*I expected to need to initialize Angular Fire in this file, but any attempt to do so resulted in failure. Eventually, I tried just including the `AngulrFireAuth`, `AngularFirestore`, and `AngularFireDatabase`, modules from Angular Fire and not the base `AngularFireModule`. This worked. Then I tried removing all AngularFire modules from the library and that worked as well. These seem to operate in a peer dependency fashion, where the library doesn't need the Angular Fire module dependencies included directly into its module, just so long as they are included into the module that actually gets run.*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: []
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**shared.service.ts**

*This file takes advantage of the `AngularFireAuth` service, even though the `AngularFireAuthModule` hasn't been included in the library module.*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

  constructor(
    private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) { }

  getClaims$() {
    return this.fireAuth.idTokenResult.pipe(
      map(idTokenResult => (idTokenResult || { claims: null }).claims)
    )
  }
}
```

### Application Module

**app.module.ts**

*In this file, we finally initialize and include the AngularFireModule, as well as the library module (`SharedModule`). For some reason, I never had to include the `AngularFireAuthModule` to get this to work.*

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { SharedModule } from 'shared'
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire'
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

*In this file, we use the service from the library module (`SharedService`) to get the user claims from the `AngularFireAuth` service.*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { SharedService } from 'shared'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styles: [],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello.</h1>
    <pre *ngIf="(claims$ | async) as claims">let claims = {{ claims | json }}</pre>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  claims$: Observable<any>

  constructor(
    private auth: SharedService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.claims$ = this.auth.getClaims$()
  }
}
```

Comment: this make sense to me but my app (with my library's module imported) is not working because of a run time error related to initialization of AF in the librarys module `[FlamelinkService -> AngularFireDatabase -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!` do you know anything that could help?

Comment: It's a little hard for me to say from just the information in your comment. Are you importing `AngularFireDatabase` in the `FlamelinkService` file? Do you have an example publicly available that I could look at?

Comment: There was a copy of @angular/fire also in the library. I just had to delete it so the app one would be used... like you said the lib did not need any mention of @angular/fire in the lib module

Answer (score -1):

Have you setup firebase environment in your angular app?
1)Go to your firebase console
2)select project ->project setting 
3)There you will get something like this:->
 var firebaseConfig object from there

4)Copy it and paste it in your angular_project_folder->src->environments->environment.ts like this

export const environment = {obj}

Comment: That's totally not what I was talking about. I have firebase config for a long time included in my project. The problem is to share it to my library module. Please pay attention when you read a question.